# When to use a <table> tag for web page?

Tags: html, css

I'm only asking because I'm going crazy trying to figure out how to display tabular data with `div` tag. I guess the simple answer to my question is: when you need a table.

But why does some website use/partially use `div` for table design? For example: http://caniuse.com/#feat=audio

And what's the point of `display:table-row-group` and similar display values when a you can just use a `table`?

Comment: A question you should ask yourself: Is it a table or just the design makes it look like one?

Answer (score 3):

Use a table for tabular data.
Don't use a table for layout.

Making charts?  Use a library.